# NoSuchMethod Exception thrown when build AvroParquetWriter in java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, avro, parquet

I am using Java and Spark and have following code

```
JavaRDD<String> uploadedFiles = resultJavaRDD.map( rdd -> {
                    
                    String localFilePath = "tmp/myfirst.parquet";
                    Path dataFile = new Path(filePath);
                    // Write as Parquet file.
                    try (ParquetWriter<MyData> writer = AvroParquetWriter.<MyData>builder(dataFile)
                            .withSchema(ReflectData.AllowNull.get().getSchema(MyData.class))
                            .withDataModel(ReflectData.get())
                            .withConf(new Configuration())
                            .withCompressionCodec(SNAPPY)
                            .withWriteMode(OVERWRITE)
                            .build()) {   // this build statment throw exception 
                        for (MyData d : rdd.getDataList()) {
                            writer.write(d);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Failed to write to the file. \n" + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    ......
                    s3Service.uploadFile(s3FilePath, localFlePath);   // my own service to upload file to S3
                    return s3FilePath;
                });
```

However, I got an error at the ParquetWriter build step. Below is the error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetFileWriter$Mode;Lorg/apache/parquet/hadoop/api/WriteSupport;Lorg/apache/parquet/hadoop/metadata/CompressionCodecName;IIIZZLorg/apache/parquet/column/ParquetProperties$WriterVersion;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;I)V
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.build(ParquetWriter.java:489)
    at com.aktana.api.command.DSESparkDriverCommand.lambda$run$3005c09$1(DSESparkDriverCommand.java:590)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1015)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My gradle is like

```
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.747'
    compile 'org.apache.parquet:parquet-avro:1.8.1'
```

The problem is if I don't use Spark, but put the same code in pure java, everything seems working fine. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a mis-reference of the class I am using. I use relocate to relocate the lib dependency of org.apache.parquet:parquet-avro and it works fine now.

Comment: how did you conclude it was a version conflict? Does your build tool relocate before compiling?